# Convert HTML back to Markdown for editing in wmd

Tags: markdown, wmd

I am curious to do what happens when you edit a post on this site.

I am using wmd for my markdown editor, of course when I goto edit, I get the HTML it generated not the markdown like on stackoverflow.  Now, is there a way I can store both?  or is it reliable enough to simply convert the HTML back to markdown to show in the wmd editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the `optionsExample.html` in your WMD distribution. There's an option to send the result to the server as Markdown.

Comment: Actually, I have seen how to get one or the other, but then I need to convert it to HTML everytime I display it.    IS that they best way to go?  Either way I think I am in the same boat.  Seems more efficent to convert it back only when editing.

Comment: You can convert to HTML on the server end, and store both HTML and Markdown in your database. That's how Stack Overflow does it, I believe.

Comment: To avoid lots of repeat sanitisations, I believe that SO also sanitises the HTML'd version before storing that in the DB. (I believe there is a SO blog entry that mentions this, but don't quote me on it.)

Comment: This is the javascritp you need to add before you load wmd.js: wmd_options = { output: "Markdown" };

Comment: @SamSelikoff Correct, but it actually has a server-side Markdown implementation to create the HTML with. It does not accept client-generated HTML willy-nilly. (Oh wait, I already said all this in my comments from 4.5 years ago. ;-))

Answer (score 14):

If you want to convert HTML to Markdown in batch, I can recommend
[Aaron Swartz’s html2text.py Python script](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) with which you can just:

```
cat my.html | python html2text.py # outputs markdown
```

**Edit 05/11/12:** Nowadays I use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) which is like a swiss-knife for text documents. Can convert html<>textile<>markdown<>epub<>pdf<>latex, etc.

Comment: Aaron's page also has a form to convert any URL to markdown. Very handy!

Comment: Second using Pandoc. Just used it now, and it's terrific!

Answer (score 2):

As Chris notes, you can send Markdown to the server so you can store it there as such. I started trying to use MarkdownJ to convert on the server-side, but it doesn't (at the time of this writing) convert images to HTML correctly and so I ended up going with Java 6 Scripting: Rhino engine + showdown.js. Since WMD uses showdown.js you get the same Markdown-to-HTML transformation. Works like a charm (for Java 6, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I have just know [Markdownify](http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/) (formerly html2text.php) that "writes texts in Markdown and save them in HTML. You won’t need a copy of the original Markdown input, since Markdownify can convert the saved HTML back to Markdown. And because page impressions are far more often than write actions, this gives you a simple way to increase your page’s performance. Another benefit for a CMS or similar software is that now only one format of text is saved — HTML. The user can now choose wether to write texts in plain HTML or use a full fledged Wysiwyg editor. And of course he can write in Markdown!"

Comment: Your online demo appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Open source html to markdown converters written in JavaScript:

- [domchristie/to-markdown](https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown)

  MarkItDown: retro-convert rich text to Markdown. [Online Try](http://markitdown.medusis.com/).
- [bambax/MarkItDown](https://github.com/bambax/markitdown.medusis.com)

  An HTML to Markdown converter written in JavaScript. [Online Try](http://domchristie.github.io/to-markdown).