# Should I use strip tags on the fly or store on server already stripped

Tags: php, javascript, htmlpurifier, wmd

I am using WMD like stackoverflow uses. I have read the upvoted posts on the topic which all advise to store both the markdown and the html_purified versions on the server. The reason for this is the markdown is needed for the user to edit his post, and the to purify on the fly is too expensive for the server so better to convert it and store it on the server.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/519322/1240324

However, when I show on the index page a bit of every question, then I dont want the markdown or the html version. I would like to call strip_tags on every question excerpt. But would this be heavy for the server to do it on the fly? Should I store a third field for a stripped tagged version?

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags() isnt particularly expensive. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, have you got a source for that?