# Running a ruby script from php

Tags: php, ruby

Ruby is installed here:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
```

Ruby script:

```
puts "Hello world"
```

Php script:

```
<?php
    $cmd = "ruby /home/balint/rubytest.rb";     
    echo system($cmd);
?>
```

I can run `sudo php /home/name/public_html/phprubytest.php` from CLI but not from the browser.

I reach the server via Putty and use Filezilla to put all my website-related files to the public_html folder.

I logged out the error and it turned out I have a permission error:

```
ruby: Permission denied -- /home/balint/rubytest.rb (LoadError)
```

This means as a user running the php script from the browser I have no access to that directory on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Ruby/Python scripts from inside PHP passing and receiving parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619996/how-to-run-ruby-python-scripts-from-inside-php-passing-and-receiving-parameters)

Comment: That is a fantastic tutorial to send and receive data and that's where I come from. I tried it, received `command returned 1` message so I decided to try out the simple script. And here I am now.

Comment: Looks like you're not allowed to read that file as the user running the PHP script.

Comment: That's right. It has -rw-rw-r-- permissions. What I did is that I copied it into the public_html folder where I have permission to run it. However, in order to run the ruby script now from php I should add the absolute path of all the gems that I use. What's the better way here, solving the permission issue or setting path for all gems?

Answer (score 0):

```
exec(rubyfile.rb);
```

Just add this code and it will execute your ruby file.